# what color does apple messages app use for the blue chat bubble background

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, colors, message

I am trying to get a color similar to the apple messages chat bubble background color.  I can't seem to find anything as bright and vivid as their blue.  Would love to know the rgb values or if they are using any other properties to make it more vivid.

Comment: Make a screenshot of it, use color pipette to find out RGB

Comment: thanks for your reply.  i did exactly that and it gave rgb values of 8 127 254.  this paints a very dark blue that is not similar at all.

Comment: it turns out I was using cmyk for my adobe illustrator file which was giving my colors a very dull look when setting rgb colors.  i just changed the illustrator document color mode to rgb and then when I exported the file and  included in my xcode image assets the colors worked perfectly.  thanks very much for your helpful suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's around (0, 120, 254).

(8, 127, 254) is similar. You probably did something wrong if it appears very different.

Comment: thanks very much.  i was using the right colors but had the wrong setting in my illustrator file.  see comment above.  still trying to figure out how to get the gradual fade on only the blue cells without effecting the other content in the scroll view.

Comment: @alionthego You can change the cell's background color based on its scroll position. Also, you should have posted these 2 questions separately since they are mostly unrelated.

Comment: i've taken your suggestion and created another question for that.  thanks.